# How do I display "Android backspace" - ⌫ in Label

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, symbols

I have a Xamarin application with a `Label` which is `Bound` like so:

```
<Label Text="{Binding BackSpace}"/>
```

and a property in my viewmodel like so:

```
public string BackSpace
{
   get
   {
        ResourceManager temp = new ResourceManager("MyProgram.ResourceStrings", typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(temp.GetString("Backspace"));
   }
}
```

now I have an element in my `ResourceStrings` called `Backspace` and I am trying to get the string associated with this key which I want to be the `Android Backspace` - `⌫`

So initially I set the resource equal to the symbol `⌫` but this just gives me a label containing `?`

Now I try set it equal to the HTML hex code from [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/232b/index.htm):  `&#x232b;` but this gives me `&#x232b;`

How do I get my label to display the `⌫` symbol?

**PS.** - Even if I try:

```
<Label Text="⌫"/>
```

I get a blank label

Comment: You'll need to change your label's font to a font which contains backspace as glyphicon.

Comment: @DanielLuberda which font would contain the `glyphicon`?

Comment: [https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-zsym](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-zsym) I can't see the icon in the list shown there I'm affraid. I will investigate fonts

Comment: Not all symbols are listed there. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your label's font to a font which contains backspace as glyphicon.

You'll need two things:

- Appropriate font. Probably Noto Sans Symbols https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-zsym. ⌫ symbol
- Label renderer which allows custom fonts. See here: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ExtendedLabel

This [Xamarin link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/) will provide more infomation on working with Fonts