# Why does "Android Backspace" - ⌫ Render differently on different devices?

Tags: android, fonts, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application using `Xamarin` and `Xamarin.Forms`.

I used an answer from a question I asked earlier: [How do I display “Android backspace” - ⌫ in Label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32351677/2987066)

To display a ⌫ icon in a Label in `Xamarin.Forms` by adding [this font (Noto Sans Symbols)](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-zsym) as an embedded resource in my project and `XLabs` [Extended Label](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ExtendedLabel) to use a custom font.

The results are the following:

**Nexus 9 Running Android 6:** (works fine as expected)
[image]

**Samsung Galaxy Tab S Running Android 5.0.2** (Weird behavior)
[image]

**Lenovo Tab S8 Running Android 5.0.1** (Weird behavior)

[image]

So the question is, why do these fonts render differently on different Android devices? And what can I do to avoid this problem?

Obviously the second 2 don't resemble backspace and aren't easily identifiable as a backspace to the end user.

Comment: Different Android devices have different fonts installed.  I know you mention its an embedded font within your application but it does sound maybe like the device its working on, has the font already installed perhaps or the device has the font but a different version of it, so the other characters show up perhaps?  If you have a small demo you can send over I will try out a few things here?  My contact details are on my profile.

Comment: @Pete thank you for the offer. I managed to solve the issue by using an image instead of the font. But thanks again for the offer

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly is XLab's label implemented. if you care, try writing your own [label renderer](http://www.dvolve.org/using-custom-fonts-in-xamarin-forms/) to make sure it's not XLab's bug .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I don't know the reason why this happens. But I did figure out a quick solution to the problem.

Instead of relying on the font to render the Icon just use an image instead

```
<Image Source="BackSpace.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="75"/>
```